# Check if a sequence is composed of two identical sequences

Tags: c++, algorithm, text, lexical-analysis

The problem is to find for a 1<=n<=50000-element sequence of numbers (1 to 10^5) if such a subsequence can be chosen that the remaining elements will create another copy of the chosen subsequence. In other words, if the original sequence was made by intertwining two copies of some subsequence. If so, we have to additionally print the original subsequence. My idea was to naively seperate every other number of the same kind into two subsequences. So, for example, the first subsequence would get 1st 5, 3rd 5 and 1st 4 and the second one would get 2nd 5, 4th 5 and 2nd 4. I thought the sequence cannot be expressed as a combination of two copies like that iff it has an odd number of some numbers in it. However, the entire approach is faulty and very rarely gives good answers;

Please help me find a more clever algorithm that will actually solve the problem. My implementation of the naive approach for better understanding (C++):

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);

    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<short> arr(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    vector<vector<unsigned short>> positions(10001, vector<unsigned short>(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        positions[arr[i]].push_back(i);
    }

    vector<unsigned short> out;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; ++i)
    {
        if (positions[i].size() % 2) 
        {
            cout << "NO" << "\n";
            return 0;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < positions[i].size(); j += 2)
        {
            out.push_back(positions[i][j]);
        }
    }

    sort(out.begin(), out.end());

    cout << "YES" << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < out.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << arr[out[i]] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I take it there are no additional constraints on how the subsequences may be intertwined?

Comment: Lacking any limitation on how the intertwining can be done, I'd simply sort the sequence, and see if it contains an even number of every value. Any more than that requires some limitation on how each sub-sequence is formed.

Comment: @JerryCoffin It's a sequence not a permutation. So a, b, b, a, c, c would not be valid, but a, b, a, c, b, c would be valid, because you can remove a, b, c from left to right in such a way that you are left with a, b, c.

Comment: You mention that you also want to find the original subsequence. What about when that's ambiguous? e.g. `aabbaabb` could be composed of either `aabb`, or `abab`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin as maraca already said, no constraint is needed since we cannot change the order of terms in the subsequences

Comment: @cigien it is enough to print just one possibility

Comment: Where is this from? Is it online somewhere for testing?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using backtracking. There is also some optimization possible. You know that the first number has to be the first number of the sequence. So all letters between the first and the second occurence of this number have to follow in the sequence. Similarly for the last number in the sequence. Additionally you could check whether there are enough numbers left to complete the sequence.

```
public int[] solve(int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length % 2 != 0)
        return null;
    int[] solution = new int[arr.length / 2];
    if (solve(arr, 0, 0, solution))
        return solution;
    return null;
}

private boolean solve(int[] arr, int i, int j, int[] solution) {
    if (i == j) {
        solution[i] = arr[i + j];
        return solve(arr, i + 1, j, solution);
    } else if (i == solution.length) {
        for (int k = 0; k + i + j < arr.length; k++)
            if (arr[k + i + j] != solution[j + k])
                return false;
        return true;
    } else {
        for (int k = 0; i + k <= solution.length; k++) {
            if (arr[i + j + k] == solution[j] && solve(arr, i + k, j + 1, solution))
                return true;
            if (i + k < solution.length)
                solution[i + k] = arr[i + j + k];
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is only checking left to right and not from both ends. Other possible improvements:

- Check if the count for each number is even at the start
- Keep track of the number count so you know earlier when a number cannot go into the first sequence any more because it has already half of them

It is Java code, but it can easily be translated to C++. Arrays are passed by reference. I tested some simple cases and for those it worked.

With memoization I could easily solve problems up to 50000 in some ms. But I had to increase the stack size to 100M. You may want to rewrite this to an iterative solution instead of a recursive one.

```
public static int[] solve(int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length % 2 != 0)
        return null;
    int[] solution = new int[arr.length / 2];
    if (solve(arr, 0, 0, solution, new Node(null, null)))
        return solution;
    return null;
}

private static boolean solve(int[] arr, int i, int j, int[] solution, Node node) {
    if (node.checked)
        return false;
    if (i == j) {
        if (node.children.containsKey(arr[i + j]))
            node = node.children.get(arr[i + j]);
        else
            node = new Node(node, arr[i + j]);
        if (node.checked)
            return false;
        solution[i] = arr[i + j];
        Node n = new Node(node, solution[i]);
        if (solve(arr, i + 1, j, solution, n))
            return true;
        n.checked = true;
        return false;
    } else if (i == solution.length) {
        for (int k = 0; k + i + j < arr.length; k++)
            if (arr[k + i + j] != solution[j + k]) {
                node.checked = true;
                return false;   
            }
        return true;
    } else {
        Node n = node;
        for (int k = 0; i + k <= solution.length; k++) {
            if (arr[i + j + k] == solution[j] && solve(arr, i + k, j + 1, solution, n))
                return true;
            if (i + k < solution.length) {
                if (n.children.containsKey(arr[i + j + k]))
                    n = n.children.get(arr[i + j + k]);
                else
                    n = new Node(n, arr[i + j + k]);
                if (n.checked)
                    return false;
                solution[i + k] = arr[i + j + k];
            }
        }
        node.checked = true;
        return false;
    }
}

private static class Node {
    public boolean checked;
    public Map<Integer, Node> children = new HashMap<>();
    public Node(Node parent, Integer value) {
        if (parent != null)
            parent.children.put(value, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks good, does it work decenty fast?

Comment: I tried your approach, also implementing your suggestions. Sadly, it's too slow.

Comment: @Kangaroo976 did you try without optimization first? It could be that it is more of an overhead. Need to optimize the else clause. The problem is probably for cases where the same number appears a lot of times at the start but the problem is not solvable. So what we could do is to memoize unsolvable numbers. E.g. aaaaaabccb would check aaa 10 times and aa 15 times.

Comment: @Kangaroo976 *"too slow"* for what?

Comment: @Kangaroo976 another version added

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode that's why I said you either have to increase stack size or you have to make it iterative without recursion.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread. Anyway, it takes [over 5 seconds for just 200 numbers](https://ideone.com/Vp2uZS).